# How to Accumulate Observables

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I should define a function, which will return IObservable<'u>

```
accumulate : ('t -> 'a -> 't * 'u option) -> 't -> IObservable<'a> -> IObservable<'u>
```

So that my function f t obs' accumulates observable events of obs into an accumulator of type 't and emits an observable event u when 'snd (f acc a)' evaluates to 'Some u' for an observed event 'a'.

So far I have implemented the function below:

```
let accumulate (f:'t -> 'a -> 't * 'u option) t obs = 
 Observable.scan (fun _ x -> snd (f t x)) None obs
```

I really don't understand how this observable scan thing works, my function returns IObservable<'u option> in this case. How can I fix that? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `fun _ x -> snd (f t x)` is incomplete. The clue is that the first parameter `_` is ignored and the first part of the resulting tuple is thrown away by the call to `snd`.

There is no accumulation because `f t x` always calls with the same value `t` that was passed originally to `accumulate`. That original `t` is supposed to be the initial value and should be passed to `scan` as part of its second parameter.

The first part of the tuple produced by `f:'t -> 'a -> 't * 'u option`is the accumulated value. So that is that part that needs to be returned to `scan` so that it gets passed to `f` again and accumulated over and over.

In your problem the requirement is to accumulate and also pass an event when the second part of the tuple is `Some 'u`. So the question is how to do both: accumulate `'t` and filter `'u`?

The answer is by combining the accumulated value with the `Some 'u` which is what `f` does. So you need to keep the tuple as the `scan` state and then afterwards keep only the second part using `choose` and `snd`.

This is what you are looking for:

```
let accumulate (f:'t -> 'a -> 't * 'u option) t obs =
    obs
    |> Observable.scan (fun (acc, _) x -> f acc x) (t, None)
    |> Observable.choose snd
```

---

## Understanding `scan`

`scan` is a function that carries a changing state by passing it to a function together with a series of values. In particular it can be used to accumulate values, for instance an `int` running total:

```
let keepTotal obs =
    obs
    |> Observable.scan (fun total v -> total + v) 0
```

This is equivalent to doing this in imperative code with a mutable `total` :

```
let mutable total = 0

let keepTotal2 obs =
    obs
    |> Observable.map (fun v -> 
        total <- total + v
        total
    )
```

notice how the 2 versions have the same elements:

- initial value: `0`
- accumulator function: `total + v`

Of course the second version, even though it uses `map`, is bad functional code because it uses an external mutable variable which is a big NO NO.

Your original problem could have been solved the same way:

```
let accumulate2 (f:'t -> 'a -> 't * 'u option) t obs =
    let mutable acc = t
    obs
    |> Observable.choose (fun x ->
        let acc2, uOp = f acc x
        acc <- acc2
        uOp
    )
```

Even though this one uses a mutable variable which is ugly in functional programming (and unnecessary) it is functionally ok, because the variable `acc` is internal and no code outside `accumulate2` can see it. Still ugly though.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain an `Observable.choose` after your `Observable.scan` to get the correct type signature

```
let accumulate (f:'t -> 'a -> 't * 'u option) t obs =
    obs
    |> Observable.scan (fun _ x -> snd (f t x)) None
    |> Observable.choose id
```